# Differences in git.exe on Windows for same git version

Tags: windows, git

I'm trying to call git with only GitHub Desktop installed. I'm finding two binaries on disk. One (43 KB) at:

`C:\Users\RNEL\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.0\resources\app\git\cmd`

Another, much larger version (3,244 KB) at:

`C:\Users\RNEL\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.0\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin`

When I run `git --version` I'm getting the same response `git version 2.29.2.windows.4`

Here's the dependencies, with the larger one having more (image below)

Why the size difference? Do they both work? Is there a command to list "features" or to somehow tell the difference between the two other than the version?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a support question for Github Desktop ?

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/The-difference-between-MINGW-and-MSYS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that one of these is a wrapper script, and the other is the actual `git.exe` binary.

Git for Windows ships a large number of Unix programs with Git Bash because Git has programs written in shell and those Unix programs are required for it to work.  However, some of those programs, like `find`, conflict with Windows binaries of the same name, so putting all those Unix programs in the `PATH` would be undesirable when running in CMD or PowerShell.  As a consequence, there are a small number of wrapper programs in one directory to invoke `git` and similar programs, and this directory is in the `PATH`, while the other one is not unless you're using Git Bash.

On a Unix system, one would use symbolic links for this, but unfortunately on Windows, symbolic links either require special privileges or Developer Mode to be enabled, and as a result wrapper binaries are used to help users in these environments.

Comment: I didn't realize an exe could wrap another exe? Is that a "thing" or is this just custom code that is implemented on a case by case basis. I'm not even sure how I would do something like this; I assume via system calls? Via absolute/relative paths (since it is not on the PATH). It's not like you're linking a library .... right?

Comment: It's just a binary that ends up spawning another binary after doing some look up to find the right binary's location.  Nothing fancy.